# Can a constructor include logic that determines which other constructor overrides to call?

Tags: c#, .net, constructor

It is posible in C# to decide in constructor, which other override constructor use? This below code doesn't compile! I don't know which invocation use.

```
    public IntRange(int val, bool isMax)
        : isMax ? this() : this()
    {
        if (isMax)
        {
            IntRange(0, val);
        }
        else
        {
            IntRange(val, int.MaxValue);
        }
    }
```

Comment: No, just extract the common logic out into private methods and call them within the constructor depending on the value of `isMax`.

Comment: Seems like it would be better to have made this decision prior to calling _any_ constructor.

Comment: Not in C#. I think it can legally be done in IL.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about:

```
    class IntRange {
      public IntRange(int val, bool isMax)
        : this(isMax ? 0 : val, isMax ? val : int.MaxValue) {
      }
      public IntRange(int min, int max) {
      }
    }
```

Comment: I would probably make isMax a default param too (false), if it's not going to be used a lot, or to just make it easier to call.

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve that kind of thing using a static method on the object as follows

```
class IntRange {

    public IntRange(int min, int max) {
       // write code here
    }

     public static IntRange Construct(int val, bool isMax) {
         if (isMax) {
             return new IntRange(0, val);
         } else {
             return new IntRange(val, int.MaxValue);
         }
     }
}
```

You could even make the constructor `public IntRange(int min, int max)` private, to force use of the static method.

I find that static methods to construct objects like that are particularly useful when one might want to create a subclass instead.

Comment: The factory method approach. Nice. I would generally make the non-static constructor private in that scenario as you note.

Answer (score 0):

It does not compile because of the statement 
        isMax ? this() : this()
in a constructor after : you can only call base class constructor or overloaded constructors of same class .